"not connected to DevTools", how can I handle this in selenium, python3?
Today, I really do my first time at selenium.
but, I can't step forward.
first, I run below code
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(3)

and got error like this
...
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5617c37fd10a <unknown>
#1 0x5617c34e35e0 <unknown>
#2 0x5617c351b921 <unknown>
#3 0x5617c35172c5 <unknown>
#4 0x5617c3563df6 <unknown>
#5 0x5617c3563446 <unknown>
#6 0x5617c35578c3 <unknown>
#7 0x5617c35256b3 <unknown>
#8 0x5617c352668e <unknown>
#9 0x5617c37c7b0b <unknown>
#10 0x5617c37cba91 <unknown>
#11 0x5617c37b4305 <unknown>
#12 0x5617c37cc612 <unknown>
#13 0x5617c379946f <unknown>
#14 0x5617c37ec008 <unknown>
#15 0x5617c37ec1d3 <unknown>
#16 0x5617c37fbf5c <unknown>
#17 0x7f1f507ad609 start_thread

So I google this error and try this
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--single-process")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(3)

and got error
...
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=129.0.6668.70)
...

I can't find same error like this.
version
selenium: 4.25.0
Google Chrome 129.0.6668.70
ChromeDriver 129.0.6668.70 (df87d5cf12b1397be7495a04cab2db6239b227a8-refs/branch-heads/6668@{#1420})
